# Default URL not loading with Carrierwave in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I'm having issues setting a default image in my carrierwave uploader. It seems to be appending a weird class to the front of the URL but not rendering the image. See my code below.

**Helper**

```
 # encoding: utf-8

class UserpicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # Include the Sprokets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end



  # Process files as they are uploaded:

  version :normal do
   process :resize_to_fill => [162, 163]
  end
  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:

     def default_url
     # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
       # asset_path("fallback/" + [normal, "profile_default_pic.png"].compact.join('_'))
       "/images/fallback/" + [normal, "profile_default_pic.png"].compact.join('_')
     end

  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :scale => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
    def filename 
      if original_filename 
        @name ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.dirname(current_path))
        "#{@name}.#{file.extension}"
      end
    end

end
```

**EDIT...**

Here is the edited code that worked. I had to put the image in public/fallback instead of Assets/images/fallback.

```
# encoding: utf-8

class UserpicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  # Include the Sprokets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end



  # Process files as they are uploaded:

  version :normal do
   process :resize_to_fill => [162, 163]
  end
  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:

     def default_url
     # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
         asset_path("fallback/" + [normal, "profile_default_pic.png"].compact.join('_'))
       # "/fallback/" + [normal, "profile_default_pic.png"].compact.join('_')
     end

  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :scale => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
    def filename 
      if original_filename 
        @name ||= Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.dirname(current_path))
        "#{@name}.#{file.extension}"
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: Apparently `normal` is evaluating to `#<#<Class:0x007ff7eb231398>:0x007ff7eca64b68>`

Comment: If I change the view to "<%= image_tag @user.userimage.url(:normal) %>" I get the following but still no image..."<img alt="Profile_default_pic" src="/images/fallback/profile_default_pic.png"/>"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My file is located in /assets/images/fallback/ folder. However, it doesn't matter what I change the URL to i.e.("/assets/" or "/images/fallback" or "/assets/images/fallback") the image does not show up.

Comment: Ok I got it working this is what I was missing...

 - The default folder had to be in the public/ folder not in assets/images
 - I had to add the following lines to the uploader class:

   **include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper**

   **include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper**

 - I had to change the default_url to the following:

   **asset_path("fallback/" + [normal, "profile_default_pic.png"].compact.join('_'))**

I hope this can help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it working this is what I was missing...

- The default folder had to be in the public/ folder not in assets/images
- I had to add the following lines to the uploader class:

  **include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper**

  **include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper**
- I had to change the default_url to the following:

  **asset_path("fallback/" + [normal, "profile_default_pic.png"].compact.join('_'))**

Answer (score 0):

edit the uploader class  :

```
def default_url  
 "/images/fallback/" + [version_name,"default.png"].compact.join('_')
end
```

and then copy the default picture in `/images/fallback/default.png`

Answer (score 0):

In **Rails 4.1.*** you can just specify the filename in the **default_url** method

```
def default_url
  "default.png"
end
```

In this case the **default.png** should be in **/app/assets/images** folder