# Rails If - Else Statement image_url to check existence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

```
<div class="img-container">
  <%= if @user.image_url.present? %>
    <%= image_tag @user.image_url(:main).to_s %>
  <%= end %>
</div>
```

I am using rails 4, and carrier wave to upload photos as mentioned in the rails casts.  So I have a column in my db that is called "image", and the above code works without the if statement.  When I use the @user.image_url(:main).to_s and it has an image it properly shows the image in the container.  I want to upload a standard photo when the user does not provide one.  It's located in my assets/images folder.

How can I get the if statement to detect if there is photo present or not in the column image?  I have to use image_url if showing the user uploaded photo.  Not just image to display the image, and the .to_s is a safety net.  Any thoughts or answers?

Thanks!

Thanks to the accepted answer, I did use the suggested carrier wave solution for Rails 4 which is recommended for 3.1 and above.  This post helped me get it corrected: [Default URL not loading with Carrierwave in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336524/default-url-not-loading-with-carrierwave-in-rails)

Comment: Does [providing a default url](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url) not do what you want already?

Comment: @pdobb it would actually, didn't know it existed.  pretty new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Great. I turned the solution into an answer then.

Comment: Also don't use a = for if/end, loops, etc. `<% if @user.image_url.present? %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a [default url](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url) with CarrierWave should do the trick. This allows for a fallback if no image is currently present.

Example:

```
def default_url
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path "fallback/main/default.jpg"
end
```

Comment: So, under images I created a folder called "fallback" then put the default.png file in there.  Can I use a .jpg?  After this would the following code work?  def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [:main, "default.jpg"].compact.join('_'))
  "/images/fallback/" + [:main, "default.jpg"].compact.join('_')
  end

Comment: Roughly, yes. I'll paste the code I use for image defaults into my answer.

Comment: Well, with your code I got an error, and not sure why.
Asset names passed to helpers should not include the "/assets/" prefix. Instead of "/assets/fallback/main/default.jpg", use "fallback/main/default.jpg" - You nor I put assets/ in front of it.  Not sure why it says this.

Comment: Maybe try just the `"fallback/main/default.jpg"` part then. Could be a Rails 4 or 4.1 thing if you're on that version.

Answer (score 1):

For **Rails 5** the one that worked for me is

`ActionController::Base.helpers.resolve_asset_path("logos/smthg.png")`

returns `nil` if the asset is absent 
and 
the asset path if present